# How to create circular ProgressBar in android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Have you any idea how to make a circular progress bar like the one of Google Fit application? Like the image below.

[image]

Comment: I've actually made something like this recently. This might be a helpful starting point? https://github.com/daentech/CircularDemo

Comment: Anyone got an answer where the edges of the loading part are rounded like in the example?

Comment: Refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509065/showing-progress-in-the-circle

Comment: @Siebe you can use the library that I mentioned in my answer .It can be customized to get loading part as you want.

Comment: maybe this can point you in the right direction https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

Comment: Sigh... Why did google did not even bother to add it on their official SDK?

Comment: you can use something like this https://github.com/emre1512/CircleProgressBar

Comment: https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar and with it you can use: `app:cpb_corner_style="round"` for rounded corners

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can try this [Circle Progress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) library

[image]

[image]

**NB:** please always use same width and height for progress views

**DonutProgress:**

```
 <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

**CircleProgress:**

```
  <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
        android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

**ArcProgress:**

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
        android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
        android:background="#214193"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        custom:arc_progress="55"
        custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY"/>
```

Comment: how they are showing values in progress i m trying setProgress in on  protected void onProgressUpdate() {

   super.onProgressUpdate();
   Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
             progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + j);
   Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate perc:" + j);
   updateMemoryAndCountValues();
   
  }
but its not working

Comment: @Top Cat how can i add animation like zoom in in circle progress or http://mikinw.blogspot.com/2013/03/glow-effect.html

Comment: I want to use DonutPrgress but want a gradient colour in progress and also rounded edge at one corner. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Very light library here -> https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar

Comment: getting unbound prefix error

Comment: how to stop this progress bar for my input percentage?

Comment: Add `android:rotation="-90"` if you want it to start from top.

Comment: Please see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801280/drawing-a-circle-and-show-data-as-per-the-data-set

Comment: Can you please guide how to set donut_progress in integer format as shown in image

Comment: library is cannot resolve to me how to solve this issue

Comment: @RevathiManoharan you might have Gradle offline mode enabled. Try disabling it and building again.

Comment: This library is abandoned as of 2017

Answer (score 342):

**It's easy to create this yourself**

In your layout include the following `ProgressBar` with a specific drawable (*note you should get the width from dimensions instead*). The max value is important here:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="500"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
```

Now create the drawable in your resources with the following shape. Play with the radius (you can use `innerRadius` instead of `innerRadiusRatio`) and thickness values.

**circular (Pre Lollipop OR API Level < 21)**

```
   <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3.8sp" >
        <solid android:color="@color/yourColor" />
   </shape>
```

**circular ( >= Lollipop OR API Level >= 21)**

```
    <shape
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3.8sp" >
        <solid android:color="@color/yourColor" />
     </shape>
```

*useLevel* is **"false"** by default in API Level 21 (Lollipop) .

**Start Animation**

Next in your code use an `ObjectAnimator` to animate the progress field of the `ProgessBar` of your layout.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, 500); // see this max value coming back here, we animate towards that value
animation.setDuration(5000); // in milliseconds
animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

**Stop Animation**

```
progressBar.clearAnimation();
```

P.S. unlike examples above, it give smooth animation.

Comment: is there a way to add text in the center of the progress bar?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to add text between them.  Shape are just drawables.

Comment: secondly is there a way to change the white color of progress bar over which our color comes to show the progress?

Comment: Everything is adjustable.

Comment: ObjectAnimator is not defined in api = 10

Comment: Yes, it is added in API LEVEL 11

Comment: https://github.com/Shah-Sahab/LimitIndicator

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Is there any  way to make end of arc rounded?

Comment: I implemented it and it's working great. But pausing and resuming animation is not available in API < 19. Have any solution for this?

Comment: @FahidNadeem there is no support for pause/resume animation in Api level < 19. For above that you can use `PausableAlphaAnimation` class.

Comment: Is there any custom way to do pause/resume in API < 19?

Comment: AFAIK no. but you can create a custom implementation for this.

Comment: Just one clarification for those who may encounter the same problem that I had: in ObjectAnimator.ofInt(yourId, "progress", 1, 500); you have to substitute "yourId" with your view, not the id of your view. So "findViewById(R.id.yourId)", not only "R.id.yourId". 

Hope it may help!

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me, how could I achieve this code **getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, Mode.SRC_IN);**

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain also with your code the greyish part in the OP circular progress bar is not visible, its transparent. Please tell me how to make it visible.

Comment: delete the style in progressbar - "progressbarstyleHorizontal", this is how you make it visible

Comment: Salam, thank you for your solution! Although not relevant to the OP but is there anyway I can make the progress continuous instead of going from 0 to 100%. For example it could show a spinning circle and when the task finishes the circle would disappear.

Comment: @SnowTauren it is relevant to the OP and thats the reason I posted the answer. Yes, you can alway tweak it.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain, no I meant what i'm asking is irrelevant :D. Can you guide me how to make a busy icon that pops up when some task is performed.

Comment: If you are using a Action bar in your app, you can use inderminate Progressbar `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)`, by using `true` and `false` you can show/hide it `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);`

Comment: I do not have actionBar, however I tweaked your code: `animation.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(3));`, and then when I have to make the circle disappear I use `animation.end();`, now the problem is that it works on some devices that I tested but not on all of them.

Comment: No no, dont do this. You can always use dialog and use progress bar which runs inderminate. Show/hide your dialog box then. Use [ProgessDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Comment: I'm working on a weather app, and I can't use a dialogBox. [Example](http://cdn.appstorm.net/android.appstorm.net/android/files/2013/06/EZ-Weather.png). This is an example of what I want to achieve. The refresh button next to 18:52 time. When the button is pressed it would spin around, when the async task completes and the weather is updated it would stop.

Comment: ohh, got the point. you just need an image and rotate it. `new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);`. This will rotate a image on its center point and you have to write the stop mechanism.

Comment: Can I use the circle shape described in your solution instead of an imageView?

Comment: I dont think so, its not an image. I had not tried it btw.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Hello I know it's a bit late, but the animation seems to be running forever. clearAnimation() doesn't seem to work. Could you please help me out ? Thanks

Comment: it should work, are you sure you are clearing animation on progressbar instance ?

Comment: Your answer looks it may working greatly.. but one picture = 1000 words.. so if you add your output as screenshot it may useful for future users - IMHO

Comment: sure, will try to do that.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain How do I start this animation from the top of the circle? As it stands, the animation starts at x = far right, y = middle, i'd like it to start at x = middle, y = top.

Comment: You need to use `rotate` element before the `shape` element.

Comment: Do I put the java code in the onCreateView of my fragment?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too.

Comment: All I see when I run this is a square of whatever color I set the `solid` to

Comment: did you follow the steps ?

Comment: How do I set progress with this? Say I want to show download progress, how do I advance the circle indicator according to download percentage?

Comment: @EZDsIt in xml via `android:progress="0"` or programtically via `setProgress` method

Comment: This seems to work if the animation is only run once. If I add a repeatmode of Reverse or add an animation end listener and restart the animation, the circle stops at the second to last tick and doesn't complete the circle. Have you seen this behavior?

Comment: How set a circular light gray backround to the progressbar?

Comment: It would be great to have a screenshot attached to the answer.

Comment: Good solution.
To set background change circular.xml to layer-list and add secondaryProgress item.

Comment: sir it works but it gives me an inaccurate animation, which is it runs fast at first at in the end it runs slowly.

Comment: `which is it runs fast at first at in the end it runs slowly.` I have used `new DecelerateInterpolator ()` which means it runs fast at first and slows down on the ending. there are multiple accelerators. Try to use none

Comment: style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
I had to change the style to this for the ProgressBar

Comment: Remember to add **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**  prefix to shape xml

Comment: can you please help me with this [https://stackoverflow.com/q/48658388/5134647](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48658388/5134647)

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Nice answer, I'm wondering if it's any way to detect when the progressbar has finished so I can clear animation and do some stuff.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS yeah, you can check the progress, if its max value reached, that you can do that.

Comment: But there's like a listener or something? to check everytime is moving?

Comment: Seekbar have progress listener, Progress bar dont. so as the alternative, you have  the `Timer` or `repeated post delayed handler`(https://gist.github.com/murtazakhussain/edb7be99ca74c398c44c) set to check for periodic progress.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I did it with a listener from AnimationObject, works great. can you see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942286/how-to-get-seconds-from-progressbar) please?

Comment: Works like a charm :) Any way to add the indeterminate behavior to this and add a color to it?

Comment: @AmanAlam yes i guess, thats pretty easy.