# Android Data Counter

Tags: android

I want to create a android view that takes in a specific number and fills up a circle depending on that number. Example of view in the following link:

[image]

This view is to view how much data has been used by the user. My question would be what would be the best way to do this? How would I make the circle fill its self depending on the data used up everytime the person checks his data usage. Any tips are welcome.
PS: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `circular progressbar` to do it and change the progress on change of the data count. You could yuse this library to do it https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress It has many different designs, so you could choose from them the one, which is best for you :)
Other possibilities you could see in the answers of this SO question [How to create circular ProgressBar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/create-circular-progress-bar)