# Circle Progress bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Anyone knows how to create or what is it called, a circle progress bar like this:

[image]

That whenever a counter increases, it starts filling. With a number inside

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android

Comment: While not Java, I've used justGage (http://justgage.com/) for web applications, including JavaScript apps on Android.  It might have some use.

Comment: Just what is was looking for! Thanks @NaN!

Comment: Ok, thanks @stdunbar i'll have a look!