# How to create a CircularProgressBar like whatsApp during image uploading?

Tags: android, android-layout, whatsapp

How to create CircularProgressBar like below where you can stop the progressbar by taping on cross image.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Adilhusen/circle-progress-ad-android

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library [CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) . It is easy to use. Here is stages:

Add this gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
```

Here is xml file

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:donut_progress="30"/>
```

For more information visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266585/3073945)

Answer (score 0):

create a progressbar tag in your layout :

```
<ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/progressBar"
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:max="100"
   android:progress="0"
   android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
```

and create a circular.xml drawable :

```
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="2sp" >
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

for API >= 21 add `android:useLevel="true"` to the shape tag in circular.xml.

then in your Activity you would just have to set the progressBar progress depending on current progress and for the cancel button you can just add a button to cancel where you like.

Comment: I have tried your answer its not working.

Comment: @WaleedSarwar if you are using API>= 21 add `android:useLevel="true"` to the `<shape>` tag in circular.xml

Comment: still not working.

Comment: well I just tested it on kitkat and lolipop and marshmallow and they all work :/ have you programitcally set the proggress of the progressbar? if you leave the progress at 0 you wont see the progressbar, set the progress to 20 or something else and you will see it works.

Comment: yes you are right its working now.But as you can see in the picture i want indeterminate mode of the progressbar.

Comment: @WaleedSarwar if you just want an indeterminate progressbar then remove the `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` and add `android:indeterminate="true"` then you can programatically switch between indeterminate and determinate progress in your activity.

Comment: Yes i have tried it but the color progressDawable is not changing.

Comment: @WaleedSarwar I am having trouble keeping up with what you want exactly, do you just want an indeterminate progressbar with color of choice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111982/discussion-between-waleed-sarwar-and-amro-elaswar).