# How to make dynamic ring progress bar in android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to create circular progress bar that shows progress of file uploading and downloading as whats app shows. I have seen number or libraries available on github. I do know this question has been asked and I have gone through those as well as mentioned in below link.

```
https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238185/how-to-create-a-circularprogressbar-like-whatsapp-during-image-uploading
```

But above links refer to library. Is there any way to create circular progress bar without using any library?

In one of the link over stackoverflow I found below code

```
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (progressBar, "progress", 0, 500); 
    animation.setDuration (5000); 
    animation.setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

But above code does not set progress dynamically. Means that progress bar works for 5 seconds. It is not mandatory that progress bar should always run for 5 seconds. File size can be vary so is progress bar. My question is how Can I make circular progress bar dynamically without using library?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

**layout Xml**

```
<ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/progressBar"
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:max="500"
   android:progress="0"
   android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
```

Now create the drawable in your resources with the following shape. Play with the radius (you can use `innerRadius` instead of `innerRadiusRatio`) and thickness values.

```
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="3.8sp" >
    <solid android:color="@color/yourColor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this link to dynamically create circular progress bar [How to Create a circular progressbar in Android which rotates on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it) or [How to create circular ProgressBar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by following way when image view holds from server it hides progress bar until file loads from sever the progress bar rotates.

```
           <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxHeight="55dip"
                    android:minHeight="35dip"
                    android:minWidth="55dip"
                    android:maxWidth="10dip"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

1.use this library may be it help you out:

https://github.com/CardinalNow/Android-CircleProgressIndicator

2. you can also try this one:

[Show Progress bar while downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695595/show-progress-bar-while-downloading)

Comment: thats why i give you two option 1. is with library and 2. is without library