# Custom Circular progress bar inner ring

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

[image: This is my Score Page]

it is a quiz app, at the end it will show the Total score, correct answer and total questions.circular progress bar is use to show correct answer out of total Questions. Problem is the green colour is moving continuously as soon as it completes the circle it again starts moving I want that it should not move.

This is Circular_done.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadius="40dp"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="270">

        <shape
            android:innerRadius="40dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="10dp"
            android:useLevel="true">


            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="0"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:toDegrees="360" />

            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#00FF00"
                android:endColor="#00FF00"
                android:startColor="#00FF00"
                android:type="sweep" />

        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Below is my xml code

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/doneProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circular_done" />
```

and my java code

```
 final int Score = extra.getInt("SCORE");
        final int totalQuestion = extra.getInt("TOTAL");
        int correctAnswer = extra.getInt("CORRECT");
        final String Cat=extra.getString("CAT");
        txtTotalScore.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d", Score));
        txtTotalQuestion.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d/%d", correctAnswer, totalQuestion));


        progressBarResult.setMax(totalQuestion);
        progressBarResult.setProgress(correctAnswer);
```

Comment: What is it that's not working? The different coloring between max and current?

Comment: duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android

Comment: @user6547359 circular bar is not working it is showing me white colour only

Comment: @Sonic that's all are moving progress bar bro

Comment: Put the drawable into android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_done" and not indefinite Edit: it's been a while, the drawable might not be done well aswell.

Comment: @user6547359 I want it to be constant not movable

Comment: Since you're not updating the progress constantly, it will be constant. You have to update the progress to make it move, just don't do it (you already aren't)

Comment: but its showing like a loading progress bar which is not what I wanted