# Android custom progressbar for pedometer app

Tags: android, android-progressbar, pedometer

I'm working on fitness app. For that app I have to make curve progress bar and in this curve I have to display foot step, calorie and goal. I am displaying as  just text view. But how to make curve progress bar I want to display daily goal? If he crossed half  target progress bar should fill half
see image. I want progress bar similar to this:

[image]

Comment: try [this one](https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView) it helps you out.

Comment: try this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27269329/6834114) it'll help.

Comment: thanks its working