# How to get seconds from ProgressBar

Tags: java, android

I have a circular progress bar that at the moment is working fine, but now I need to add like a `TextView` or something to know how many seconds left.

This is my `ProgressBar`

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:max="500"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
```

Then I have this `Drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:useLevel="true"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="3.8sp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

And for testing I put 5 seconds as follows :

```
ProgressBar progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, 500);
        animation.setDuration(5000);
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();
```

I've tryied with `addUpdateListener` to know the current animated value but I realized that is 0 to 500.

What I've tried is something like : `(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue()/ 60) * 100)` but it's not working.

How could I do this where I can add dynamically the duration (5 seconds) and show it on a `TextView`?

Also I'm wondering why my `ProgressBar` is not starting from the top and is starting for right side.

If you have any other way to do that feel free to comment. My goal is to show a `ProgressBar` that the duration is dynamic and then show the seconds left on a `TextView` until now I have the `ProgressBar` but the rest is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `CountDownTimer` instead. Create a `CountDownTimer` with your desired duration, say 5 seconds, and then on each tick, update the `ProgressBar` and the `TextView`. It will give you the duration remaining.

```
    // Creating a CountDownTimer for 5 seconds, that will call onTick every second.

final int totalTime = 5000;
new CountDownTimer(totalTime, 100) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long secondsRemaining = ( millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        // Updating the TextView with seconds remaining
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(secondsRemaining));

        // Calculating the progress out of 100.
        int progress = (int) millisUntilFinished / totalTime;

        // Creating an animation to smoothly update the progress bar between each tick.
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", progressBar.getProgress(), progress);
        animation.setDuration(100);
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start(); 
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // done
    }

}.start();
```

Comment: You can calculate the progress of the progress bar, and then update it within the onTick. Seconds remaining / Total Duration = percent complete. Then update your progress bar with an animation if you want.

Comment: feel free to put an example, also why my progressbar is not starting at 12? and it's starting at 3?

Comment: I improved my example on how to update the views, you will need to tweak the values to make it feel right. But that should give you an idea on how to do it. As for the starting position, I don't know, maybe rotate your drawable.