# Android circular progress bar with round edges using XML

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I would like to implement something like the one described here while *avoiding the use of a library*

[How to create circular ProgressBar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android/)

I tried this way, which seemed to work fine for most people:

[How to create circular ProgressBar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/how-to-create-circular-progressbar-in-android/27269329#27269329)

My only problem (2 problems):

- Can't get round edges (like the ones in the question's picture) because  has no effect on ring shape
- What if I want to make a non-full circle?

Can I achieve my goal using just XML? (no Canvas, no custom view)

Comment: no, you cannot do that using xml only: you have to use a custom `Drawable` class and `Cnavas` API

Comment: @pskink why should I use a Drawable?

Comment: because you need it for [ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgressDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method